# An upper bound for the continuum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The ZFC set theory cannot prove (nor disprove) the continuum hypothesis.
However, is this theory powerful enough to give an upper bound ? What I mean by this is a result like :
$$ 2^{\aleph_0} \leq \aleph_n $$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Thank you for your answer,

Comment: Only restriction on the value of $2^{\aleph_0}$ over $\sf ZFC$ is that the corresponding cardinal should have uncountable cofinality.

Comment: This is a very natural question, but has been asked on this site multiple times.